# How to segment an id based on daily device usage for each day

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Objective:** I would like to segment Ids based on their device type usage per day. If an Id uses solely pc then 'pc'. If only mobile, then 'mobile'. If at least 1 mobile and 1 pc then 'both'.

**Sample data:**

```
CREATE TABLE #test1 (
    dates DATE
    ,id INT
    ,device CHAR(30)
    )

INSERT INTO #test1
VALUES  
('2018-01-01', 123, 'pc')
,('2018-01-01', 123, 'pc')
,('2018-01-01', 123, 'mobile')
,('2018-01-01', 123, 'mobile')
,('2018-01-01', 800, 'mobile')
,('2018-01-01', 800, 'mobile')
,('2018-01-01', 800, 'mobile')
,('2018-01-01', 500, 'pc')
,('2018-01-01', 500, 'pc')
,('2018-01-02', 123, 'mobile')
```

**This is what i tried so far but to no avail:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT dates
    , id
    ,CASE 
        WHEN device = 'pc' AND device = 'mobile' THEN 'Both'
        WHEN device = 'pc' THEN 'pc'
        ELSE 'mobile'
        END AS x
FROM #test1
```

**My output should look like this:**

```
+------------+-----+--------+
|   dates    | id  |   x    |  
+------------+-----+--------+
| 2018-01-01 | 123 | both   |  
| 2018-01-01 | 800 | mobile |  
| 2018-01-01 | 500 | pc     |  
| 2018-01-02 | 123 | mobile |  
+------------+-----+--------+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `group by dates, id` and `count` the distinct values of `device`:

```
SELECT dates
    , id
    ,CASE COUNT(DISTINCT device)
        WHEN 1 THEN MAX(device)
        WHEN 2 THEN 'both'
     END AS x
FROM #test1
GROUP BY dates, id
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c683fc2d858975cc5694e94a4fea77e4)

Answer (score 3):

`CASE` expression eventuate once per row so it doesn't work the way that you write so, you can use use `exists` :

```
select distinct t.dates, t.id, 
      (case when exists (select 1 from #test1 t1 where t1.dates = t.dates and t1.id = t.id and t1.device <> t.device) 
            then 'both' 
            else t.device 
       end) as x
from #test1 t;
```

Comment: this works too but can't seem to get my head around it. im not sure if this will cause performance issues when querying millions of rows.

Answer (score 2):

This should help you or give you an idea:

```
;WITH cte AS (SELECT DISTINCT dates, id
                , CASE device WHEN 'pc' THEN 1 WHEN 'mobile' THEN 2 END AS x
            FROM #test1)
SELECT dates, id, 
    CASE SUM(x) WHEN 1 THEN 'pc' WHEN 2 THEN 'mobile' WHEN 3 THEN 'both' END
FROM cte GROUP BY dates, id
```

Potentially, you can have even more items, just code them in powers of 2 as 1,2,4,8,16 etc.

Comment: very creative. this is very helpful indeed when more conditions needs to be applied